# How can I make the scrollbars only apply to the tabs, not the content?

Tags: html, css, tabs

How can I make the scrollbars appear directly below the tabs and only apply to the tabs, not the content?

Here is my code in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g3gvg0j4).

```html
<head>
  <title>Test Page</title>
  <style>
    .wrapper {
      width: 800px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    
    .tab-radio {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .tabs {
      font-size: 0;
      margin: 10px 0;
      overflow-y: auto;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    
    .tabs:after {
      clear: both;
      content: '';
      display: table;
    }
    
    .tabs .tab {
      display: inline;
    }
    
    .tabs .tab-label {
      background: #eee;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 1rem;
      left: 1px;
      margin-left: -1px;
      padding: 5px;
      position: relative;
      vertical-align: bottom;
    }
    
    .tabs .tab>[type="radio"] {
      clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
      height: 1px;
      opacity: 0;
      position: fixed;
      width: 1px;
      z-index: -1;
    }
    
    .tabs .tab-panel {
      display: inline-block;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      height: 0;
      width: 0;
    }
    
    .tabs .tab-content {
      display: block;
      float: left;
      font-size: 1rem;
      width: 100%;
      white-space: normal;
      overflow-y: visible;
    }
    
    .tabs .tab [type="radio"]:checked+.tab-label {
      background: white;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .tabs .tab [type="radio"]:checked~.tab-panel {
      display: inline;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tabs">
      <div class="tab">
        <input class="tab-radio" type="radio" id="tab-tab1" name="tabs-main" checked>
        <label class="tab-label" for="tab-tab1">Tab Caption 1</label>
        <div class="tab-panel">
          <div class="tab-content">
            <h2>Tab 1</h2>
            <p>A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text.
              A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text.
              A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text.
              A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text. A long piece of text.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">
        <input class="tab-radio" type="radio" id="tab-tab2-0" name="tabs-main">
        <label class="tab-label" for="tab-tab2-0">Tab Caption 2</label>
        <div class="tab-panel">
          <div class="tab-content">
            <h2>Tab 2</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">
        <input class="tab-radio" type="radio" id="tab-tab2-1" name="tabs-main">
        <label class="tab-label" for="tab-tab2-1">Tab Caption 3</label>
        <div class="tab-panel">
          <div class="tab-content">
            <h2>Tab 3</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">
        <input class="tab-radio" type="radio" id="tab-tab2-2" name="tabs-main">
        <label class="tab-label" for="tab-tab2-2">Tab Caption 4</label>
        <div class="tab-panel">
          <div class="tab-content">
            <h2>Tab 4</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">
        <input class="tab-radio" type="radio" id="tab-tab2-3" name="tabs-main">
        <label class="tab-label" for="tab-tab2-3">Tab Caption 5</label>
        <div class="tab-panel">
          <div class="tab-content">
            <h2>Tab 5</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">
        <input class="tab-radio" type="radio" id="tab-tab2-4" name="tabs-main">
        <label class="tab-label" for="tab-tab2-4">Tab Caption 6</label>
        <div class="tab-panel">
          <div class="tab-content">
            <h2>Tab 6</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">
        <input class="tab-radio" type="radio" id="tab-tab2-5" name="tabs-main">
        <label class="tab-label" for="tab-tab2-5">Tab Caption 7</label>
        <div class="tab-panel">
          <div class="tab-content">
            <h2>Tab 7</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">
        <input class="tab-radio" type="radio" id="tab-tab2-6" name="tabs-main">
        <label class="tab-label" for="tab-tab2-6">Tab Caption 8</label>
        <div class="tab-panel">
          <div class="tab-content">
            <h2>Tab 8</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">
        <input class="tab-radio" type="radio" id="tab-tab2-7" name="tabs-main">
        <label class="tab-label" for="tab-tab2-7">Tab Caption 9</label>
        <div class="tab-panel">
          <div class="tab-content">
            <h2>Tab 9</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">
        <input class="tab-radio" type="radio" id="tab-tab2-8" name="tabs-main">
        <label class="tab-label" for="tab-tab2-8">Tab Caption 10</label>
        <div class="tab-panel">
          <div class="tab-content">
            <h2>Tab 10</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I am looking for a non-JavaScript solution. Thanks.

**EDIT**

I have looked at different ways to structure the tabs so that the tabs are separate from the tab panels. Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/artlawry/pen/domFD). Unfortunately, that will not suffice because it uses IDs for the tabs in the CSS file. That will not work because tabs are sometimes added and removed dynamically and the same CSS file is used on different pages.

I have decided to offer a bounty as soon as the question becomes eligible. I will still award a bounty to the best answer if the problem is solved before then.

**EDIT**

I will no longer be offering a bounty because I solved the question myself, unless however, someone can solve the issue of the tabs not staying highlighted without JavaScript. I don't think that it is even possible.

Comment: this is a structuring issue. You cannot scroll something that is not in the same parent element. You need to first make all the tab headers and then the body elements

Comment: I am hoping to not have to completely restructure everything because my code works fine most of the time. The only time there are problems are when there are too many tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by moving the labels into a separate `div` and using the `focus` hack to highlight the tabs. The only downside is, I will still need to use JavaScript to keep the selected tab highlighted and to select the first tab when the page loads.

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9xctj304/1/).

I cannot award a bounty to my own answer, however, if anyone manages to make it work correctly without JavaScript, I will happily award a bounty.